# Do I have to necessarily arrive in Germany on the date of the airline ticket I submitted for my visa application?

Tags: germany

For applying for my German student applicant visa, they asked me to submit an airlane ticket. Now my question: does one have to necessarily fly in on the same day of a ticket?

It may be that certain circumstances of mine change and I wish to fly into Germany at a different date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must obey the dates stated in the visa itself (not the visa application).

They're usually:

- the date the visa was issued
- the date the visa first becomes usable or valid
- the date by which you must have entered the issuing country
- the maximum duration of the visa, or alternatively the expiration date of the visa (that is, the date by which you must leave the issuing country).

If your plans change such that you wish to travel earlier, or stay longer, then you must seek an amendment to the visa or secure another visa before you travel.